# Update DataTable on Tap event in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to calculate euclidean distance of two points. Initial distance is calculated in the data.

Then, when the user is moving the line, I'd like the `distance` column to update based on the new coordinates. I can see that `x` and `y` columns are updating, but not the `distance` column. Below is my attempt:

```
output_file("tools_point_draw.html")

_tools_to_show = 'box_zoom,pan,save,hover,reset,tap'        

p = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=_tools_to_show,
           plot_width=862, plot_height=604,
           title='Plot name')

p.background_fill_color = 'white'

d_true = {'x': [2, 3], 'y': [4, 1], 
          'color': ['red', 'red'],
          'desc': ['true','true']}

df_true = pd.DataFrame(d_true)
df_true['distance'] = np.sqrt(np.sum((df_true['x'] - df_true['y'])**2))
source = ColumnDataSource(df_true)

renderer2 = p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='color', size=15,
                      line_color='red', line_width=5)
renderer = p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='red',
                  line_dash='dashed', line_width=10)

columns = [TableColumn(field="x", title="I am X"),
           TableColumn(field="y", title="I am Y"),
           TableColumn(field='color', title='color'),
           TableColumn(field='desc', title='desc'),
           TableColumn(field='distance', title='distance')]

update = CustomJS(args=dict(source_data=source), code="""
    var data = source_data.data;
    var f = cb_obj.value; //is this necessary?

    //Sum of squares for euclidean
    for(var i = 0, i < data['x'].length; i < size ; i++) {
        var res += Math.pow(data['x'][i] - data['y'][i], 2)
    }

    //Take square root
    var res2 = Math.sqrt(res)

    //Update table
    data['distance'] = res2

    source_data.change.emit();

    """)

update.js_on_change('tap', update)

table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, editable=True, height=200, width=862)

draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer, renderer2], empty_value='black')
p.add_tools(draw_tool)
p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

show(Column(p, table))
```

Comment: when you show code it is helpful to also include the imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback actually never triggers here. It's just the pointdraw event doing its thing.
You should have your callback trigger when source.data is changed.

```
source.js_on_change('data', update)
```

I did it for distance from the first point but you could do from origin too.

If it's from the first point you need to update all the distances each time (since the draw tool lets you drag existing points)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import DataTable, TableColumn, Column, PointDrawTool, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

output_file("tools_point_draw.html")

_tools_to_show = 'box_zoom,pan,save,hover,reset,tap'        

p = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=_tools_to_show,
           plot_width=862, plot_height=604,
           title='Plot name')

p.background_fill_color = 'white'

d_true = {'x': [2, 3], 'y': [4, 1], 
          'color': ['red', 'red'],
          'desc': ['true','true']}

df_true = pd.DataFrame(d_true)
df_true['distance'] = [0]+[np.sqrt((df_true['x'][i]-df_true['x'][i-1])**2+(df_true['y'][i]-df_true['y'][i-1])**2) for i in range(1,len(df_true['x']))]
source = ColumnDataSource(df_true)

renderer2 = p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='color', size=15,
                      line_color='red', line_width=5)
renderer = p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='red',
                  line_dash='dashed', line_width=10)

columns = [TableColumn(field="x", title="I am X"),
           TableColumn(field="y", title="I am Y"),
           TableColumn(field='color', title='color'),
           TableColumn(field='desc', title='desc'),
           TableColumn(field='distance', title='distance')]

update = CustomJS(args=dict(source_data=source), code="""
    var data = source_data.data;
    var res = 0;

    //Sum of squares for euclidean
    for(var i = 1; i < data['x'].length ; i++) {
        res += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(data['x'][i] - data['x'][i-1], 2)+Math.pow(data['y'][i] - data['y'][i-1], 2));

        //Update table
        data['color'][i] = 'red';
        data['desc'][i] = 'true';
        data['distance'][i] = res;
    }

    source_data.change.emit();
    """)

source.js_on_change('data', update)

table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, editable=True, height=200, width=862)

draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer, renderer2])
p.add_tools(draw_tool)
p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

show(Column(p, table))
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! I could not figure it out, so I found other solution in the meantime (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

While I could not find a way how to update the table, I simply added a Div and updated the text inside. Not elegant, but it gets the job done.

```
div_euclid = Div(text="""
               <b>Diameter of predicted form is:</b> 334.80 <br>
               <b>Diameter of true form is:</b> 368.64 <br>
               <b>RMSE is:</b> 34.13
               """, 
               align='center',
               style={'font-size': '100%'})

p.js_on_event(events.MouseMove,      
            CustomJS(args=dict(div=div_euclid, 
                              source_data_pred=src_pred,
                              source_data_true=src_true),
     code="""
     var data_p = source_data_pred.data;
     var data_t = source_data_true.data;

     var x_p = data_p['x']
     var y_p = data_p['y']

     var x_t = data_t['x']
     var y_t = data_t['y']

     var diam_p = 0
     var diam_t = 0
     var rmse = 0

     //Diameter of pred form
     diam_p = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x_p[0]-x_p[1]),2) + Math.pow((y_p[0]-y_p[1]),2))

     //Diameter of true form
     diam_t = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x_t[0]-x_t[1]),2) + Math.pow((y_t[0]-y_t[1]),2))

     //RMSE
     rmse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(diam_p - diam_t,2)/1)

     //Result
     div.text = "<b>Diameter of predicted form is: </b>" + diam_p.toFixed(2) + "<br> <b>Diameter of true form is: </b>" + diam_t.toFixed(2) + " <br> <b>RMSE is: </b>" + rmse.toFixed(2);

     """))
```